# Display a map of two vectors

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I would like to display my map of two vectors.
Could you help me please.

```
 std::map<vector<double>,vector<int>> path;
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'display' ?

Comment: To see it an output in the console

Comment: Iterate over keys and values of std::map, then iterate by each key and each value.

Comment: Yes thank I was thinking about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be gundreds of way to do that. Here is one:

```
template<class T> void dumpVector( const std::vector<T>& vect )
{
    for ( std::vector<T>::const_iterator iter = vect.begin();
          iter != vect.end();
          ++iter )
    {
        std::cout << " " << *iter;
    }
}

for ( std::map<vector<double>,vector<int>>::const_iterator mapIter = path.begin();
      mapIter != path.end();
      ++mapIter )
{
    std::cout << "Map key:";
    dumpVector<double>( mapIter->first );
    std::cout << " has value:";
    dumpVector<int>( mapIter->second );
    std::cout << std:endl;
}
```

Hope this helps.